# HDF5 inflate error on windows

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, hdf5, h5py

I've being using a dataset in HDF5 file to feed a convolutional neural network during the training.,

My code is written in Python using the Keras library. The function which provides the data to the CNN is a generator. When the computer is not being used, the processing works fine without any error. However, when I start to use it, the code aborts with an inflate error:

```
...

  File "E:\MATLAB\2018, Autoencoder\utils.py", line 311, in listImgNameToBatch
    im_tmp = self.hf_AD.get('/AD/' + im_name)[im_idx]

  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

  File "C:\Users\Helder\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\dataset.py", line 496, in __getitem__
    self.id.read(mspace, fspace, arr, mtype, dxpl=self._dxpl)

  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

  File "h5py\h5d.pyx", line 181, in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.read

  File "h5py\_proxy.pyx", line 130, in h5py._proxy.dset_rw

  File "h5py\_proxy.pyx", line 84, in h5py._proxy.H5PY_H5Dread

OSError: Can't read data (inflate() failed)
```

The dataset is not corrupted, since I checked the MD5 hash of it. It was created using the compression level 5. The error does not happen in the same point. Sometimes the training pass 20 epochs to abort, sometimes 5 epochs, depends if the computer is being used... And more than that it does not raises the error immediately, it takes a while. For me its sort of random event which causes the reading to crash.

Does anybody is experiencing the same behavior? Is that a problem of HDF5 lib or of windows? Unfortunately, I dont have a linux machine to test it and using a VM is not a option since I'm processing in GPU.

Any information will be welcome.

Comment: Facing same issue on google colab.